# Asp.net Mvc How do I use DropDownListFor without setting the selected in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Parent model with a list of child models. In the view I'm rendering the children using a template like so

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChildItems)
```

In the child model template I have this drop downlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Quantity, 
      new SelectList(new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }))
```

but I don't know how to set the selected item.

Most examples I see are simple controller create the list, set the selected and pass to the view.

Unless I am, in the controller to do something like

```
ViewBag["Child_1_SelectedItem"] = children[0].Quantity 
ViewBag["Child_2_SelectedItem"] = children[1].Quantity
```

which I don't see how I'd get the view to understand that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another overload on the `SelectList` constructor which accepts the selected item, so you're almost there with your second code snippet

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
var list = new SelectList(array, 1);
```

Given this, could you change your code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Quantity, 
  new SelectList(new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }, model.Quantity))
```

Edit:
It seems you can't access the lambda parameter outside of the first argument (which makes sense), but you should be able to do this (assuming Model is the same type as model, subtle difference):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, 
  new SelectList(new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }, Model.Id))
```

Or, using a simple variable:

```
@{
    int selectedQuantity = Model.Quantity;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, 
  new SelectList(new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }, selectedQuantity))
```

Comment: I thought that was it too when I saw that overload. However it oddly complains it doesn't know what model is. Cannot resolve symbol model.

Comment: Thanks Steve!! I just created a simple sample project and came to the same realization.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically do :

```
var quantities =  new List<SelectListItem>(new[] {
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = true, 
            Text="1",
            Value="1"
        },
        new SelectListItem { 
            Text="2",
            Value="2"
        }
        ....
```

And then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Quantity, quantities)
```

Seems annoying but you could build this on the controller like this:

```
var q = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in q)
{
    if(children[item].Quantity)// dunno what is in this property...
    {//if Quantity is bool you could directly set Selected then..
      list.Add(new SelectListItem {  Selected = true, Text = item.ToString() });
    } else {
      list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.ToString() });
    }
}
```

And then pass your `list` down to the view. OR you could just do this in a `@{..}` code block in the view itself.